# How to create index for clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I have about 5e9 (15e4 records per hour) records stored in clickhouse. The records is time-sequential. When I run some query with a time_range of 10 minutes:

```
select * from table_name where tag1='xxx' and 'tag2'='xxx' and server_time > '2020-01-01 00:00:00' and server_time < '2020-01-01 00:10:00'
```

It stucked. I didn't create a index. But the clickhouse index from document seems different from B-Tree index in MongoDB. So how should I create the index? Further more can you make a easy explaination?

Answer (score 1):

What table engine do you use?
The main table engine for storing the data in Clickhouse is `MergeTree`, where  some sort of index ("sparse index") is provided out-of-box.

In your case you can create table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  server_time DateTime,
  tag1 String,
  tag2 String,
  ...
) ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY time
```

Part `ORDER BY time` will do the job for you: now all of the requests with filter by `server_time` will use the index.

You can read more about MergeTree and index at official documentation: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/mergetree/#primary-keys-and-indexes-in-queries

Answer (score 0):

You need Data Skipping Indices. Check this

1. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/improving-query-performance/skipping-indexes/
2. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/alter/skipping-index
3. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/improving-query-performance/sparse-primary-indexes/sparse-primary-indexes-design/